# ZipArchive InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter, memorystream

I am getting the following InvalidDataException thrown when opening an archive made up from a FormFile.

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could
>   not be found.'
>    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
>    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
>    at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream)

### Creating the archive FormFile

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

using (var entryStream = zip.CreateEntry("hello.txt").Open())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write("hello");
    }
}

// The stream itself is 52 bytes long.
var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "file", "hello.zip");
```

### Opening the archive FormFile

```
using (var filestream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    // Exception thrown when instantiating ZipArchive
    var zip = new ZipArchive(filestream);
}
```

Comment: What if you try to insert `stream.Position=0;` before `var file =`?

Comment: If you add something like `File.WriteAllBytes("hello.zip", stream.ToArray());` **outside** the `using` block, the stream will be written to a file. `zip` is disposable and needs to be added to the `using` statements there. The MemoryStream can be disposed of later (or not).

Answer (score 3):

`ZipArchive` is disposable, and calling `Dispose()` is required to finalize the zip file, so either call `zip.Dispose()` or wrap it in `using` before using the underlying stream.